# Prevent apply to coerce data frame rows as an array

Tags: r, apply

I need to use the `apply()` function over a data.frame which has columns of different data types.

The documentation of `apply(X, MARGIN, FUN, ...)` says:

> If X is not an array but an object of a class with a non-null dim value (such as a data frame), apply attempts to coerce it to an array via as.matrix if it is two-dimensional (e.g., a data frame) or via as.array.

In my example, numeric columns are casted to strings but I want to avoid calling `as.numeric()` in the base function. Is there any other alternative to avoid coercing to an array? (eg. coerce as list)

Example code:

```
df <- data.frame(name = "A", number = 1.0)

echo <- function(row) {
  data.frame(
    name = row["name"],
    number = row["number"],
    stringsAsFactors = FALSE
  )
}

copy <- apply(X = df, MARGIN = 1, FUN = echo)

class(copy[[1]]$number)

[1] "character"
```

Comment: Using `apply()` on a data.frame is usually a bad idea. you can often just use a properly vectorized function on the data.frame columns. Worst case you can `split()` by row and apply a function to the list. Can you describe more specifically what you are trying to do?

Comment: Also you are `apply`ing over rows which I think is the source of your problem. Someone else can step in if I say anything incorrectly, but what essentially happens is each row is treated as a vector. Since your row has both a character and numeric value, everything gets converted to the most flexible type (i.e. character).

Comment: Try for instance using the same code on `data.frame(name = 2.0, number = 1.0)` and `data.frame(name = T, number = 1.0)`

Comment: Yeah, I see... I have a df which each row has the coordinates of the center of a given geohash and its lat and lon error. For each row, I need to generate another dataframe, each one with 4 rows containing the coordinates and the geohash's corners and its id. Then I need to rbind all these small dfs into a big one and use it with ggmap to plot polygons.

Comment: So what you are essentially trying to do is melt your data frame. Have a look at `reshape2::melt`. This might help : https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/7439/how-to-change-data-between-wide-and-long-formats-in-r